# How to change Dropbox directory on Ubuntu 16.04 outside of encrypted home folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, dropbox

In November this year, Dropbox will stop sync in case home folder is encrypted (full disk encryption is supported). I have tried to move synch folder outside /home to folder on the Ext4 partition but every time I try only get a message that I need to move my Dropbox to the partition with the compatible file system and that is Ext4 supported (well well I use Ext4).

I have tried many things but on setting up dropbox up it is always set up in the user's home folder and after that, I am not able to change it.

Is there any solution other than switching to full disk encryption?

This is a message

[image]

New location in on diffrent hdd and on Ext4 partition.

[image]

Comment: How did you install dropbox?

Comment: Version from dropbox site.

Comment: What happens exactly when you change the "Dropbox folder location" in the Preferences -> Sync tab? Is the new folder positively ext4, with appropriate permissions, and is it on a usb or removable drive? Or are you using a different version from the ubuntu deb version, 32/64bit, or built from source? Or the headless version?

Comment: @Xen2050 I have added a screenshot of message and location is on /dev/sdb1,  second hard drive, permissions are ok. AFAIK there is nothing fancy about my version of Ubuntu :)

Comment: I've also tried this - I have an encrypted homedir, so I created a folder owned by my user in /var, which isn't encypted, and tried to move Dropbox there. No joy, get the exact same error message.

Comment: @JamesSmith Thank you for verification, so I am not crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question just in case someone else needs this. This is a kinda stupid bug on DropBox side. My source is this post from 4 days ago.

https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Error-messages/Ubuntu-16-04-Error-moving-files-to-new-ext4-location/m-p/304937/highlight/true#M18302

Apparently, from box folder need to be on a certain level for app accept change, there is no valid reason for this but workaround worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Dropbox has brought back support for ZFS, XFS, Btrfs and eCryptFS

Dropbox has brought back support for ZFS, XFS, Btrfs and **eCryptFS** on Linux. A Dropbox [client update](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Desktop-client-builds/Beta-Build-77-3-127/td-p/354660) brings back support for ZFS and XFS on 64-bit Linux systems, and eCryptFS and Btrfs on all Linux systems. Dropbox has brought back sync support in case home folder is encrypted with eCryptFS.

Links:

- [Dropbox Brings Back Support For ZFS, XFS, Btrfs And eCryptFS on Linux](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/dropbox-brings-back-support-for-zfs-xfs.html)
- [Maestral](https://github.com/SamSchott/maestral-dropbox) lightweight open source Dropbox client for Linux